# What does the final て in 待ってて signify?

Tags: translation, て-form

In this scene a young girl, Yotsuba, drops in on her neighbors for some breakfast. The mother who's cooking breakfast says:

> 「今お父さんの焼いてるからその次ねー。ちょっと待っててー。」

So I guess she's preparing her husbands food first, and tells Yotsuba to hang on for a minute.

But why didn't she just say ちょっと待って?

[Image redacted]

Comment: I started to be worried about copyright issues.  Can you check if posting a comic like this is allowed or not?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto This would fall under fair use under the US copyright law I believe

Comment: As a US citizen, I will assume fair use. http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl102.html

Comment: @Ken, @Louis: Maybe you are right.  But (1) I know almost nothing about the US copyright law and I cannot tell if it is fair use or not, and (2) although I know that Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc. is a company based in the US, I do not know if it is sufficient to follow the US laws.  Many users are from Japan, for example.

Comment: I think Wikipedia gives a bettter definition of what fair use (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) is, nevertheless, this issue should be discussed on meta.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, I didn't really consider Stack Overflow Internet Services, the image is hosted by imgur.com. Perhaps I should have though. I will ask about it on the SE meta. I should add that I don't think being for profit or non-profit is the deciding factor in fair use law.

Comment: @Louis: According to the pages you and Ken cited, profit or non-profit is among the many deciding factors, but I do not know if it is _the_ deciding factor in this particular case.

Comment: I would like to say that I think this shouldn't be a big issue. It isn't like we publishing the entire comic. It is a small snippet for educational and demonstrative purposes. Don't freak out, it's okay. The record/movie industries have trained us to think that any little copy is bad. It's not.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, it's just that I've seen so many examples of fair use by for profit businesses/individuals (a TV network showing another networks video clip, for example). I think the law is referring to using the copyrighted work with the intention of profiting from the work itself.

Comment: If this were a Wikipedia article, this use would not be allowed.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Fair_use#Policy  I do not think that the Stack Exchange network has a similar policy, but the rationale written there sounds quite reasonable.

Comment: I think it satisfies the en.wikipedia.org policy. Which part of the policy are you referring to? Comic panels are pretty common on en.wikipedia, Yotsuba's wiki has a panel as well.

Comment: Oh, and thank you for asking on Meta Stack Overflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94645/clarifying-fair-use-regarding-a-stack-exchange-site-and-an-imgur-hosted-image

Comment: I thought that it violates the minimal extent of use (policy 3b) and the specification of source (item 2 of the [image use policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Image_use_policy#Requirements)).

Comment: I only used a portion of the work, so I guess you feel the resolution is too high? Wikipedia's concern with resolution is that high resolution images could "undermine the ability of the copyright holder to profit from the work." But I don't think that is a possibility with my photo. About the source, it is in the alt attribute. Maybe that's not the best place to put it.

Comment: (1) I was not talking about the resolution.  You give the necessary context in the question text accurately, and the picture does not seem to be necessary to ask this question.  (2) I did not realize the image had an alt attribute!  (At least it is not shown with Firefox unless you choose “View Image Info” from the context menu or change the browser setting.)

Comment: Because I don't fully understand my agreement with SE, I have removed the image.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, @Louis, @Ken: I went ahead and opened a meta discussion: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/190/what-should-be-our-policy-about-copyrighted-images. I'd be glad if you could weigh in.

Comment: I changed my opinion and now I agree with what you wrote in [this post](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/190/what-should-be-our-policy-about-copyrighted-images/191#191).  Sorry for causing a lot of noise in the comments to your question.

Comment: ちょっと待っててー is an extremely common phrase. I'v heard it from women and girls many times. Does it have feminine nuance to it? I only remember hearing it from women.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Thank you for bringing this up. I'm hearing so much about this general topic with [Section 230-d](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/47/230) entering the public debate arena. What I learned from everything over ten years ago has been a good pilot light for me even today–I basically agree with the answer on meta, which may be  the unpopular opinion. So thank you, it is a great example of a bold edit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like Mark says, it's short for 待っていて, which is the て-form of 待っている. I think it's a little softer than saying ちょっと待って, and since Yotsuba is not one of the family, the mother is being a little more polite. Saying ちょっと待って can sound a little short. The meaning changes with the extra て, but I can't describe how it changes well. Something like "please be there waiting".

Comment: btw is it true that 待て is also acceptable compared to 待って ?

Comment: Nope, not in this situation. 待て is the imperative (like 食べろ or 飲め), it's a command to wait. It's too direct/impolite to use as a replacement for 待って unless you're commanding the other person to wait.

Comment: ok cool, initially i'd always thought 待て　is way more common than 待って

Answer (score 6):

Other than soft / politeness on using 待って(い)て、 I think it has some sense that you don't have to stop what you are doing now to wait, and you may do something else while waiting.

Comment: Do you have anything to back up this "I think"? I've never heard this interpretation before.

Comment: @Derek, Nope, I don't have it, that's just how I feel it. And I have no idea why mine is accepted.

Comment: You've got an interesting idea there. I can't say I've got anything better, except that to me it "feels" like using ～ている puts more emphasis on waiting for a length of time. 聴いていてね ("listen [for more than just a little while]") versus 聴いてね ("listen [even if it's just for a bit]").

Comment: Oh...I first chose nevan's answer, but I thought you were explaining that last bit that he couldn't put into words.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's short for 待っていて. Though I'm just taking a guess in the dark here.

Comment: This is correct; the い is often dropped in casual conversation.

Comment: I don't think think the poster was asking what it meant; I think they were asking about the difference between 待ってて and 待って when asking someone to wait.

Comment: Well I was wondering both. 待っていて, makes sense. But still the いて seems almost superfluous.

Comment: @Louis: Perhaps this could be broken out into a separate question?

Comment: Hmm...feel free to, but I think I got the gist of it from nevan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

could it possibly mean "you only have to wait a little while." because of the ite being there.. chotto modifies matte which equals wait a little (while) and ite means to be/exist/stay so therefore, 'a little bit wait is' could be a rougher interpretation.