# what does second て mean after て-form?

Tags: て-form

There is a phrase said by a native speaker in a video and the subtitles (not autogenerated) were:

そんなゴミの中で**寝てて**快適なの。

I cannot find what does this second て mean. The form 寝て must refer to continuous action, but then before the 快適 adjective there is one more て. What is the meaning and the name for this construction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [て form followed by て, 「見てて」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25452/45489)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!