# What is this て doing?

Tags: grammar

ちょっと忘れ物を届けてくるから、待って**て**。

This て in bold, what does it express?
I'd translate the sentence like this:
"Because I just deliver lost articles, wait."
I can only think of the imperative making sense here, but I still don't know what this additional て does.

Comment: This て is an abbreviation for いて.

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/948/9831